# Derivative of exponential function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm supposed to determine $f'(0)$ given $f(0)=0$

$$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}.$$

My method was taking log and differentiating which on rearranging gives

$$f'(x)=\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}.$$  How should I proceed further?

Comment: But $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$. Did you mean the piecewise function,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&\text{for }x\neq0\\0&\text{for }x=0\end{cases}\quad?$$

Comment: @user170231 yeah its defined at 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

I would simply use the definition of  a derivative:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\mathrm e^{-\tfrac 1{x^2}}}{x},$$
and do some asymptotic analysis – setting $u=\frac1{x^2}$, it becomes
$$f'(0)=\lim_{u\to \infty} \pm\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\mathrm e^u},$$
which is a standard limit from high school.

Comment: How to riguously show that $f'(0)$ must exists?

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll: This depends on what you' re supposed to know. It is a classical result that for any $a$, $\lim_{u\to\infty}\dfrac{u^a}{\mathrm e^u}=0$. If you need to prove it, you may consider the logarithm of the expression, and use the high-school limit $\;\dfrac{\ln u}u\to 0$ when $u\to\infty$.

Comment: I found it hard to proof such limit using epsilon-delta notation, and also hard to proof that $\lim_{x \to 0}$ can be transform to $\lim_{u \to +\infty}$ (how do you convert limit of real values function to limit of sequence without first showing that $f$ is continuous?).

Comment: $\dfrac{u^a}{\mathrm e^u}$ *is* continuous. As to the limit of  $\dfrac{\ln u}u$, you first show that for any $u>0$, $\ln u<\sqrt u$ by considering the derivatives.

Comment: I can only plot it but cannot proof it, any hints?

Comment: can I proof $e^x > x$ instead?

Comment: For you last question, no, because the inequalities are not in the correct sense. For your  previous question, you can use this corollary of the *Mean value theorem*: ` If $f,g$ are differentiable functions on an interval $I$, and $a\in I$, if $f(a)\le g(a)$  and if, on the interval $I$, $f'(x)\le g'(x)$, then, for all $x\in I, x>a$, one has $f(x)\le g(x)$.`